# Is the call of Invoke method asynchronous?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm not sure whether the call of Invoke method is asynchronous or not? Hope someone can explain this. If you can provide some documents which describe it, that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to the Hyperledger Fabric docs transaction execution for the Invoke transaction is asychronous.

> The response to a chaincode invocation request will contain a `status`
> element confirming successful completion of the request. The response
> will likewise contain the transaction id number for that specific
> transaction. The client may use the returned transaction id number to
> check on the status of the transaction after it has been submitted to
> the system, as the transaction execution is asynchronous
>
> -- [Hyperledger Fabric docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/f599ea785ae69897d5d486ba1f524e52e1ef2da8/docs/API/CoreAPI.md)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the point quoted the cjcroix's answer more clear, Fabric documentation do specify the following statement in relation to the REST API in the fabric docs
 [[Fabric Documentation : CORE API]](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/API/CoreAPI/)

> "The response to a chaincode invocation request will contain a status element confirming **successful completion** of the request. "

But **status** here is just the status of the submission process. The actual status of your invocation is as mentioned in the next line depending on the logic of the code which you are trying to invoke

> The client may use the returned transaction id number to check on the **status of the transaction after it has been submitted to the system**, as the transaction execution is asynchronous.